# Sequelize association N:M

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I don't know why the associations with Sequelize don't work for me. I have tried several functions but I cannot enter the syntax of N: M. I have tried several methods but none works for me. If anyone can help me thank you. These are my tables and my statements.

user.js

```
'use strict'

const sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../database/database')

const modelUser = db.define('usuarios', {
    idusuario: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    username: {
        type: sequelize.STRING
    },
    password: {
        type: sequelize.STRING
    },
    email: {
        type: sequelize.STRING
    },
    victorias: {
        type: sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    muertes: {
        type: sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    admin: {
        type: sequelize.INTEGER
    }
}, {
    timestamps: false
})

module.exports = modelUser
```

title.js

```
'use strict'

const sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../database/database')

const modelTitle = db.define('titulos', {
    idtitulo: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    titulo: {
        type: sequelize.STRING
    }
}, {
    timestamps: false
})

module.exports = modelTitle
```

titles_users.js

```
'use strict'

const sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../database/database')

const modelTitle = db.define('titulos', {
    fx_idtitulo: {
        type: sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    fx_idusuario: {
        type: sequelize.INTEGER
    }
}, {
    timestamps: false
})

module.exports = modelTitle
```

controllers.js

```
const TitlesUsers = require('../models/titles_users')
const Users = require('../models/user')
const Titles = require('../models/title')
    TitlesUsers.belongsTo(Users, {foreignKey: 'fx_idusuario', sourceKey: 'idusuario'});
    TitlesUsers.belongsTo(Titles, {foreignKey: 'fx_idtitulo', sourceKey: 'idtitulo'});

const users = await Users.findOne({ 
        include: [{model:Titles}],
        where: {idusuario:req.user}
    })
```

ERROR:

```
(node:11284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeEagerLoadingError: titulos is not associated to usuarios!
    at Function._getIncludedAssociation (D:\Repositorios Git\battle-royale-simulator-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:715:13)
    at Function._validateIncludedElement (D:\Repositorios Git\battle-royale-simulator-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:619:53)
    at options.include.options.include.map.include (D:\Repositorios Git\battle-royale-simulator-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:516:37)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function._validateIncludedElements (D:\Repositorios Git\battle-royale-simulator-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:511:39)
    at Promise.try.then.then (D:\Repositorios Git\battle-royale-simulator-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1723:14)
    at tryCatcher (D:\Repositorios Git\battle-royale-simulator-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (D:\Repositorios Git\battle-royale-simulator-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:517:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (D:\Repositorios Git\battle-royale-simulator-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:574:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (D:\Repositorios Git\battle-royale-simulator-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:619:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (D:\Repositorios Git\battle-royale-simulator-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:699:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (D:\Repositorios Git\battle-royale-simulator-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (D:\Repositorios Git\battle-royale-simulator-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (D:\Repositorios Git\battle-royale-simulator-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (D:\Repositorios Git\battle-royale-simulator-api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
(node:11284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11284) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the relations using `belongsToMany`:

```
Users.belongsToMany(Titles, {through: TitlesUsers, foreignKey: 'fx_idusuario'});
Titles.belongsToMany(Users, {through: TitlesUsers, foreignKey: 'fx_idtitulo'});
```

See examples in the [Sequelize docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations).